# jQuery on button click, show specific div from the parent clicked button

Tags: jquery

I have a list stucture that looks like this:

```
<ul class="categories_video">
    <li class="sanea_test">
         <h3 class="h3_clickme">some text</h3>
         <ul></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="categories_video">
    <li class="sanea_test">
         <h3 class="h3_clickme">some text</h3>
         <ul></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="categories_video">
    <li class="sanea_test">
         <h3 class="h3_clickme">some text</h3>
         <ul></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is: WHEN H3 is clicked, the UL that is next to the H3 must display:block(at the moment it is display:none)...

I tried to write something like this but it just doesn't want to work as it should :(

```
jQuery('.h3_clickme').on('click', function (evt) {
    var $button = jQuery(this);
    var $ul = $button.closest('ul');
    var $div = $ul.find('.sanea_test');
    jQuery('.sanea_test').not($div).hide();
    $div.toggle();
 });
```

PLEASE can somebody give me a hand on this. Thank you a lot!!

Comment: It looks like an accordion... It's very easy, you could use next("ul") to select the ul from the H3. Or select the parent/the closest li and not the closest ul ...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r7z2veqn/2/

Comment: Thanks to "Arun P Johny", it works perfectly thanks :))

Comment: Thank you everybody for your help, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Jump to the parent of clicked `h3`, and find `ul` inside it.

```
$(".h3_clickme").click(function(){
    $(this).closest(".sanea_test").find("ul").toggle();
});
```

[**See DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/9oo5b342/2)

Answer (score 1):

You can find h3 parent  then find ul and toggle it

```js
jQuery('.h3_clickme').on('click', function (evt) {       
    var $this = $(this).parent().find('ul').toggle();
    $("li ul").not($this).hide();
 });
```

```css
li ul { display: none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="categories_video">
    <li class="sanea_test">
         <h3 class="h3_clickme">some text</h3>
         <ul>a</ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="categories_video">
    <li class="sanea_test">
         <h3 class="h3_clickme">some text</h3>
         <ul>b</ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="categories_video">
    <li class="sanea_test">
         <h3 class="h3_clickme">some text</h3>
         <ul>c</ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi there. Yep this works great, but how do you HIDE the PREVIOUS ul that was opened?

Comment: click again on `some text`

Comment: I know that but I can't say to the users click twice on the same button :)

Comment: I think this is what you want

Answer (score 1):

See [jQuery.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to select the next sibling element.

```
$(".h3_clickme").click(function(){
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```